# Java loops,how to increment by different values?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have an array, and I'd like to go through it with a for loop in the following way:use 2 element then skip 2 elements,then use 2 elements etc.
So for instance if I have and int array : `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`
I'd like to work with 1 and 2 then skip 3 and 4 ,then again work with 5,6 skip 7,8 etc.
Is this possible in java?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please show what you have tried.

Comment: If the array is `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, should it also print out the '5' or will the array always be an even number?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i += 4) {
    // work with i and (i + 1)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of this pseudo code will do the job:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length-3; i+=4) {
    int first = array[i];
    int second = array[i+1];
    //int third = array[i+2]; //skip this
    //int fourth = array[i+3]; //skip this
}
```

Note: normally when looping through an array you can just use `i<array.length-1`, but because you could be skipping 2 at that point I believe you want to decrease the "OK" length of the array by 2 more.

Update: actual working Java code using a toggle:

```
boolean skip = false;
for (int i=0; i<test.length-1; i+=2) {
    if (!skip) {
        System.out.println(test[i]);
        System.out.println(test[i+1]);
    }

    //int third = array[i+2]; //skip this
    //int fourth = array[i+3]; //skip this

    skip = !skip;
}
```

Comment: Be careful when using `i+1` and `i = array.length - 1`.

Comment: I think it should actually be along the lines of `array.length-3` then, right?  To ensure that we can skip 2/use 2.

Comment: I don't think that `array.length - 3` will do it e.g. `int[] test = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`.

Comment: Updated using a toggle to determine if we're reading the values or skipping over them.  I think this is the simplest way rather than using modular math or subtraction to determine when to proceed in the loop.

Comment: The use of a toggle here makes it easier to follow than a complicated for-loop trying to manipulate the variables in it

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a loop, but two would be simpler.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 4)
    for (int j = i; j < i + 1; j++)
        System.out.println(j);
```

Also you can do

```
IntStream.range(0, N)
         .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(i+1, i+3))
         .forEach(System.out::println):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce as many variables as you need inside of a `for` loop and iterate through those.  It's similar to using two loops with the advantage being that there's no extra iterations being done.

The main thing here is that you're skipping four entries in your array every time.  This applies to both variables, and you also want to be sure that both of them are less than the length of the overall array (so you don't step off of it by mistake).

```
for (int i = 0, j = i + 1; i < array.length && j < array.length; i += 4, j += 4) {
    System.out.printf("(%d, %d) ", array[i], array[j]);
}
```